# Restart the PHPStorm debugger

Tags: phpstorm

The PHPStorm debugger is really amazing, but I just can't figure one thing out. How do you "Re-Start" the debugging sessions quickly?

I mean let's say I am debugging a function and I make some changes to the code. Now right now I have to

1. Stop the debugger (Ctrl+F2)
2. Go into the browser and reload the page
3. If i don't do step 1 then there are multiple debug sessions running in PHPStorm

So it would be really amazing if:

1. The old debugger closes when I refresh the page (right now it keeps running)
2. I.e New debugging session closes all previous ones (similar to Adobe Flex)

*Is that possible?*

Comment: How does IDE should know if you are planning to open another debug session or continue with current one? If IDE would have a button that would re-fresh website in browser straight from IDE then yes -- your desired bahaviour makes perfect sense. But since IDE is actually independent from the browser, you need to decide what to do yourself.

Comment: The best alternative I can think of right now .. is to have some test CLI script where you call that function -- this way IDE controls the script directly and can restart it at any time. Surely, not every function/script can be debugged this way (e.g. if it depends on web-browser specific stuff to be present, like POST/GET fields etc, but that can rather easily be mocked up .. and you should write your functions in a way so that they can be tested independently).

Comment: The browser has a Jetbrains chrome extension, so it can signal the IDE that the page has reloaded (or the last instance has been replaced or removed).